# passing JavaScript function as function pointer to C++ dll

Tags: javascript, c++, function, pointers, node.js-addon

I am trying to call an external function from `node.js` and pass it another function as a callback.

I have a dll written in C++ with the following function

**cppDll**

```
typedef bool(*Callback)(bool, const char*);

DLL_EXPORT BOOL Connect(const char *userName, const char *password, Callback callback)
{
    MessageBox(0, userName, password, MB_OK);
    callback(true, "User is connected");

    return true;
}
```

---

and my js files looks like this

**ces.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');

var constString = ref.types.CString;
var bool = ref.types.bool;

var callback =  ffi.Function(bool, [bool, constString]);

const ces = ffi.Library(path.join(__dirname,"cppDll"), {
    'Connect': [bool, [constString, constString, callback]]
});

module.exports = ces;
```

---

**main.js**

```
 var ces = require('../ces');

    ces.Connect("user", "Password", function (sec, data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

the C++ messageBox pops with the correct `userName` and `password` and that is how I know that the dll function was invoked. But the javascript's `alert(data)` is never called.
I tested the dll using C++ code and the callback function was triggered.
Any suggestions?

Comment: See [Callbacks](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_callbacks) in the node.js documentation.

Comment: thank you for your replay but this doesnt solve my problem...

Comment: I'm not great with javascript but after studying the code you posted I have one question. Why is function capitalized when you write ffi.Function?

Comment: This is the ffi defenition

Comment: Simply calling another language's functions is rarely enough. The calling convention could be different. There could be hidden state-tracking parameters such as C++'s `this` to get in your way. I don't know Javascript, but interfacing C++ with other high level languages usually require helpers such as what Remy suggested.

Comment: @NirBenZeev Exactly what user4581301 said. Ordinary Javascript functions cannot be passed as-is to C/C++ using plain function pointers. You have to wrap them in something that can cross programming language boundaries. Like the "Addon Callbacks" in node.js, `ctypes.FunctionType` in Mozilla, `ffi.Callback` in FFI (this one is probably what you are looking for), etc.

Comment: thank you. this solved the problem

Comment: @NirBenZeev thanks for posting this question! I have one question, how are you compiling that c++ dll?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`ffi.Callback`](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial), for example:

ces.js

```
var path = require('path');
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');

var constString = ref.types.CString;
var bool = ref.types.bool;

const ces = ffi.Library(path.join(__dirname,"cppDll"), {
    'Connect': [bool, [constString, constString, 'pointer']]
});

module.exports = ces;
```

main.js

```
var ces = require('../ces');
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');

var constString = ref.types.CString;
var bool = ref.types.bool;

var callback = ffi.Callback(bool, [bool, constString], function (sec, data) {
    alert(data);
});

ces.Connect("user", "Password", callback);
```